# Create multi-series boxplot from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have a dataframe with some calibration data, each row is a calibration record with the revision of the unit and the % error at different scale capacities. I would like to create a boxplot of this data, where I have the capacity columns along on the x-axis, further broken down by revision. Rather similar to the example provided in Seaborn's boxplot documentation (where smoker = revision, day = capacity). I've tried to copy the example but can't seem to get the hue argument to work without explicitly defining both x and y. I'm not sure how to do this considering I have multiple x series. I'm rather new to pandas and figure I need to restructure the data in a longer form so that there is only one x-axis. How would I go about doing this to accomplish my goal? I can provide more info if needed.

[Here's the seaborn example I'm trying to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ12o.png)

I have set up an example dataset to exhibit its current structure for reference:

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mxSi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself if anyone else stumbles across this. Needed to melt the dataframe into 3 columns first:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Revision'], value_vars=['20%','40%','60%','80%','100%'], var_name='Capacity', value_name='% Error')
ax = sns.boxplot(x='Capacity', y='% Error', hue='Revision', data=df, palette='Set3', showfliers=False)
```